# IMP-00403 while executing IMP command

Tags: oracle

I am getting `IMP-00403:` error and a separated `sql` file while executing `IMP` command. I am executing it as `IMP system/password fromuser=A touser=A`. I read that I should execute this sql file `catexp.sql` before performing this operation and I did that, but the problem still occurs. I checked the database user roles and I cannot find the `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` role for user `SYSTEM` but only for `SYS`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says:

> IMP-00403: Warning: This import generated a separate SQL file "string" which contains DDL that failed due to a privilege issue.
>
> Cause: The import failed because the DDL had insufficient privileges.
>
> Action: Connect as SYSDBA and run the SQL file.

Did you check the SQL file that was created? What's written in there?

Comment: Yes I did, and the SQL file is empty, it does not have any content.

Comment: Does import's log file contain some useful information? BTW, which Oracle version is it? Are source and target databases' versions same or different?

Comment: The export was made on Oracle 12c and the IMP is executed on Oracle 19c. Nope there aren't any other information besides this one, and as I said the sql file is empty.

Comment: Just saying: export should have been done with EXP 12, import with IMP 19. When such an error appears, there is a SQL file which should be executed before importing data; that's usually some CREATE TABLE and such. But - in your case - this is an empty file so there's nothing you could run. There's also nothing in log file. Conclusion: I'm confused and don't have any other idea ...

Comment: Hi overkail - did you ever to the get to the bottom of this issue? I am currently experiencing the exact same problem.